# Convert a YUV video stream to mp4

Tags: macos, mp4, h.264, yuv

How to record YUV video and encode it to mp4 using h264 coded for mac application.
Plz suggest me any link on it.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated a little: why YUV, do you have a capture device that outputs YUV or have you got a raw YUV file? Do you want to encode it on a mac or for use on mac? The latter being largely irrelevant if you encode it with std H.264 in an mp4 container.

Comment: @Ralf: I haven't any raw YUV file and also I haven't any capture device which outputs YUV file. I have to create a mac library which records YUV video from camera and convert it into mp4

Comment: Have you looked at VLC at all?

Comment: @Ralf: No, I haven't looked at VLC, actually I want to convert the video to mp4 using ffmpeg. If, you have any idea. Plz explain.

Comment: I have already install the FFmpeg in my mac. But how can I convert the videos to MP4 pro-grammatically.

Comment: Is that what you want? https://ffmpeg.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFMpeg can encode YUV to mp4(H.264) via libx264 encoder. But you have to specify exact YUV pixel format of your source video. There are several YUV formats.

> This command converts `rawvideo` with pixel format of `yuv420p` to a `MPEG-4 or x264` format.
>
> ```sh
> # Converts the raw yuv420p data to a MPEG-4 video
> ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 25 -i 'in' -f mp4 'out'
> ```

Below list shows YUV pixel formats can be decoded by ffmpeg.

```
$ ffmpeg -pix_fmts 2>&1 | grep yuv
yuv420p    
yuv422p    
yuv444p    
yuv410p    
yuv411p    
yuvj420p   
yuvj422p   
yuvj444p   
yuv440p    
yuvj440p   
yuva420p   
yuv420p16le
yuv420p16be
yuv422p16le
yuv422p16be
yuv444p16le
yuv444p16be
yuv420p9be 
yuv420p9le 
yuv420p10be
yuv420p10le
yuv422p10be
yuv422p10le
yuv444p9be 
yuv444p9le 
yuv444p10be
yuv444p10le
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. "Invalid buffer size, packet size 34419 < expected frame_size 115200
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument"

Comment: I think this answer has nothing todo with it!

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to convert video formats using MacOSX command line (any version). First download this compressed file and unpack it to your Movies Folder:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NlLwMD4yd9QU0yVGJyU1NiUDA/view?usp=sharing

You will then have a MMedia_Converter directory with two apps: MMedia_Convert and Android_Converter. Those are my own developed MacOSX open source applications, bassed on FFMpeg Group and HandBrake Group France previous work. Both are fully compliant Mac compilled applications and you´ll have have to do nothing but extract them to your Movies Folder.

You also have there, 3 folders: clip_in, clip_out and scripts.

You must put the videos you want to be converted in the clip_in folder.

The converted output videos, will be generated automatically in the clip_out folder.

In addition you have 2 bash scripts, that you must move to your Mac OSX Desktop.

Once these bash are on desktop, edit them with TextEdit, and change my user name by your Mac name.

In my case, I use one script to generate thumbnails and the other to generate thumbnails too, and to automatically convert videos from any formar to wathever I choose.

"Whatever" means, that if you want to convert mpeg to mkv, you will have to declare it in line: `DEST_EXT=mkv` (or wathever known video format you want).

Hope this will help you all.

Best Regards, Tomás Hernández